# Por qué no puedo cambiar datos de tipo string a int?

Tags: python, string, revisión-de-código, conversión-de-tipos, pycharm

Intento crear un programa en pycharm que pida al usuario ingresar un número de 3 dígitos y al convertir los dígitos de string a int me arroja un error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ¿Por qué ingresas un espacio antes de los tres números? Podrías hacer `num = input("blabla").strip()` para eliminar espacios al principio y final pero debes comprender el error, simplemente es que el primer carácter de la cadena es ese espacio (ingresas `" 333"` no `"333"`) y lógicamente un espacio no es un entero válido... Por cierto, nunca agregues el código en una imagen, dificulta su reproducción, su lectura y no indiza para futuras búsquedas. Agregalo como texto siempre, las imágenes pueden ayudar, pero son accesorias siempre.

Comment: En otros temas, cuál es el objetivo de `cond1`, `cond` y `resultado`? Ya sé que son condiciones, pero por las imprimes por pantalla? Además no hay forma de validarlas.